# Plone Hotfix 20121106

Tags: plone, hotfix

Im new to plone and linux and im trying to install the new patch on plone (Plone Hotfix 20121106)

Im using buildout to install this one and it seems that as i check my log, it's not downloading/installing the patch at all.

Here is the eggs content of my buildout.cfg:

```
eggs = 
    Products.PloneHotfix20110928
    Products.Zope_Hotfix_20110622
    Products.PloneHotfix20121106
```

what i did is stop the plone service first then do

```
sudo ./bin/buildout -Nv
```

and start my plone again.

and as i check the instance.log

it only installed Products.PloneHotfix20110928 and Products.Zope_Hotfix_20110622

anyone help me pls?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check if the hotfix is included in your `bin/instance` by grepping for the name (so `grep PloneHotfix20121106 bin/instance`. Make sure there are no other `eggs` entries that may be used instead for your Plone instance.

Comment: Also, always let us know your Plone version when submitting this kind of question.

Comment: Completely separate note: Never run buildout as root, which you're effectively doing by using "sudu ... buildout". In a network environment, buildout fetches untrusted code from the Internet and directly executes it.

Comment: You can check if the hotfix is included in your bin/instance by grepping for the name (so grep PloneHotfix20121106 bin/instance. Make sure there are no other eggs entries that may be used instead for your Plone instance -> I FIND NO MATCH ON PloneHotfix20121106, I'M JUST WONDERING THE WHY BUILDOUT.CFG IS NOT DOWNLOADING THE HOTFIX. BTW, I INSTALLED THE HOTFIX BY DOWNLOADING THE ZIP FILE AND UNZIP IT TO THE PRODUCTS FOLDER AND RUN bin/instance fg ... THAT FIXED THE PROBLEM BUT I'M STILL FIGURING OUT WHY BUILDOUT IS NOT INSTALLING THE HOTFIX

Comment: Completely separate note: Never run buildout as root, which you're effectively doing by using "sudu ... buildout". In a network environment, buildout fetches untrusted code from the Internet and directly executes it. -> I TRIED RUNNING WITHOUT SUDO BUT I ENCOUNTERED ERRORS (OError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/plone/.../.mr.developer.cfg'), WITH SUDO, I FIND NO ERRORS BUT I WILL TAKE NOTE OF THAT. THANKS A LOT

Comment: You don't need to repeat the other comment, nor use all caps. The `help` button next to the comment field shows you how to use *italics* or **bold** formatting if necessary to get your message across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Placed the patch (PloneHotfix20121106) to Products folder on Plone,
2. Unpack the zip file,
3. run instance (bin/instance fg)
4. start the plone service

Answer (score 0):

Check in your eggs directory to make sure the egg has been downloaded there, if not re-run buildout and watch/grep the console messages to make sure it gets downloaded successfully. If it doesnt come down for some reason you can manually download it and add it to your eggs directory.

THen if you start Plone in foreground you should see the hotfix being installed in the console messages eg

```
bin/instance fg
```

then you should see some output in the console like:

2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied registerConfiglet patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied setHeader patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied allow_module patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied get_request_var_or_attr patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied kssdevel patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied widget_traversal patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied gtbn patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied kupu_spellcheck patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied membership_tool patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied queryCatalog patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied uid_catalog patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied renameObjectsByPaths patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied at_download patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied safe_html patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied python_scripts patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied getNavigationRootObject patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied crypto_oracle patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied crypto_oracle_protect patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied ftp patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied atat patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Applied random_string patch
2012-11-06 23:51:08 INFO Products.PloneHotfix20121106 Hotfix installed

Comment: bin/instance fg SOLVED THE PROBLEM BUT I DID NOT USE BUILDOUT, I JUST PLACED THE DOWNLOADED ZIP HOTFIX TO PRODUCTS FOLDER AND RUN THAT COMMAND AND I HAD IT INSTALLED. THANKS A LOT

Comment: if you run buildout with -v flag and observe the console messages you should see when it tries to download the egg which will give you a clue what is happening... if it never tries to download the egg then you might need to investigate if you are actually using the buildout file you think you are... maybe throw some garbage in the file and see if it complains when you try and run it.